# Virtual filesystem acting as a clone+difference of a master filesystem

Tags: server, partitioning, filesystem, users, database

At my company about 10 devs share an ubuntu dev server. We have separate code directories, but due to our database size (about 50 GB), it isn't practical to clone the mysql database for each developer. So right now, we are all sharing a single database. However, I was wondering if this is possible:

Create a master filesystem (ext4) that stores the 50 GB database. This filesystem would not have a mysql server running on it and would be in-practice read-only. Create a virtual filesystem for each dev that references the master filesystem and stores a diff of each change to it. Have a mysql server running on each virtual filesystem. Then, each developer gets his own database to do whatever he wants with, while not needlessly duplicating the 50 GB database.

I haven't looked at how mysql stores its data on the disk, but due to the desire to minimize disk i/o, I suspect that the small changes that we make in our routine testing won't create a huge diffs in the virtual filesystem.

Specifically, these are my questions:

- Is this architecture possible?
- Is this the easiest way to accomplish my goal?
- Does such a virtual filesystem already exist?

Comment: Server software is used to share a resource to many users at the same time. Duplicating that resource for each user beats the purpose of having a central server. Presumably you have a backup of the data, so even if a a developer damages the database by accident it should be just a matter of restoring the data. Keep in mind that more running servers require more processing power also. It is not clear by your description what you intend to gain from introducing this type of complexity to your system. Don't forget that at the end of the day its all about cost vs gain (financial/productivity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions (next time, please number them so it's easier to refer to them):

- Should be possible
- Does NOT sound like the easiest way
- Yes, such a virtual FS does exist.

Your idea sounds like a good use case for an [overlayfs](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/mszeredi/vfs/+/overlayfs.current/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt). You can use your existing database FS as the "lower" filesystem, and a per-developer "diff" FS as the "upper" filesystem. Overlayfs allows using directories as "upper" and "lower" so you don't need to necessarily mount databases in different directories.

Then you'd need to configure each per-developer MySQL instance to use a different datadir.

By far the easiest way is to bite the bullet, equip your server with a say 1-TB hard drive, clone the database however many times you need for each developer, and either run a MySQL instance for each developer, or have one instance manage all the databases. The difference for the developers here is specifying a different port vs. a different database name. IMHO it'd be simpler to just have one MySQL instance, as it means less moving parts.

The factor to consider here is how long it'll take you to develop the overlayfs solution vs. how much a 1-TB hard drive costs for your particular server hardware. Your time has a cost; if you're looking at 3 days of work at (say) $50 an hour (being VERY conservative here) for a total of $1200, and the hard drive solution implies 2 hours of work plus maybe an overnight database sync which you can fire-and-forget, then you'd have a $1100 budget for a 1-TB hard drive. Plus maintenance for the big disk solution is easier since there are no "hacks" or trickery involved; it's just a DB server with a huge hard disk.

Of course, if your Ubuntu server lives in the cloud somewhere, the cost of that 1TB storage slice may be higher. Still, please do consider the cost/benefit analysis to make your decision; you may end up saving money and time in the long run :)